# Model comparison using ANOVA with significant interaction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction

This seems like a simple question, but I can't seem to find a clear answer, so perhaps it isn't...

Let's suppose I fit a two-way linear model with interaction term. So in R,

```
fullmodel <- lm(Y ~ A * B)
```

now

```
summary(model)
```

will give me marginal significance values for A, B and the A*B interaction. Looking at my output, I note that the interaction is significant, meaning that given that A and B are in the model, adding the interaction between them is warranted.

But I want to test the hypothesis that "B is important in predicting Y". To do this, my instinct is to use ANOVA to compare a model with B to one without.

```
ANOVA(modelwithB, modelwithoutB)
```

To me, it seems logical that

```
modelwithoutB <- lm(Y ~ A)
```

and so the comparison should be

```
ANOVA(fullmodel, modelwithoutB)
```

This means that I compare a model with just A to one with both a main effect of B and an A*B interaction. Do people concur? Or is there something flawed in my reasoning (or perhaps in my hypothesis)?

Comment: this seems correct.

Comment: Welcome to the stats.stackexchange.com. Indicate briefly about sample data and characteristics of data as well as your objectives.

Comment: I think you should plot the interaction to try to understand it better. From a statistical/technical standpoint, you are right. The comparison is a to the main effect and intersection. My concern is if you are missing something substantively important by doing this.

Comment: Thanks. Of course you are right about examining the interaction, and in this case the comparison I describe does produce significance for B so I would be examining the full model. This question was prompted by a table of marginal significances in which the B main effect is weak and non-significant but the A*B interaction is strong and significant. (And the A main effect is significant.) My interpretation of this is that B acts largely as a modifier of the relationship between Y and A. And I suppose I could demonstrate B being 'important' simply by pointing to the t-test significance of the mar